# How to transform two strings into key/value pair Zod validation from React Form

Tags: reactjs, zod

I want to convert these two strings into an object with key/value pair and being validated in zod:

```
{authors.allAuthors.map((author) => {
            return (
              <option key={author._id}>
                {author.firstName} {author.lastName}
              </option>
            );
          })}
```

And this is my schema entry for authors:

```
authors: z.string().transform((val) => JSON.parse(val))
```

My problem is that while doing so I'm receiving this error from the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

What to do?

Comment: Could you share a few more details? My general experience with JS makes me think there's a separate issue causing the error you're seeing (looks like you're trying to read the length of an array that's actually `undefined` and since it's within a promise there's some context missing). Could you share the code where you're calling `parse` on your form data?

Comment: Solved fetching just author._id from database :)